# JavaScript : What is it about my code that means the second image only displays for a nano-second

Tags: javascript

I am using a function, HideFrame to hide/show the left of two iframes.  The function is called by an onclick() event using buttons image1 and image2.

Unfortunately, when I click image1 to hide the left frame, image2 only displays for a nano-second before image1 displays again.

What have I done wrong?

I am just a beginner so go easy on me.

```
function HideFrame() {
var fr = window.top.document.getElementById ("body_left");
var fs = window.top.document.getElementById ("body_right");
var img1 = document.getElementById("image1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("image2");


if(fr.style.width=="33.5%") {
fr.style.width="0%";
fs.style.width="99.5%";
img1.style.display="none"; 
img2.style.display="inline";


}
else {
fr.style.width="33.5%";
fs.style.width="65.8%";
img1.style.display="inline"; 
img2.style.display="none";

}
}

<input type="image" src="./hideframe.png"  id="image1"
style="display:inline"              
title="Hide/show left panel" onclick="HideFrame()"/>

<input type="image" src="./showframe.png"  id="image2"  style="display:none"
title="Hide/show left panel" onclick="HideFrame()"/>
```

Comment: A nanosecond is 10^(-9) seconds (a billionth of a second). I am not sure the human eye is able to see things that flash by in a nanosecond.

Comment: Of course I was exaggerating to make a point.

Comment: @999999 no one said the OP is human.

Comment: for a second I thought I was still on reddit!

Answer (score 2):

Clicking the image submits your page, which causes it to re-load and image 1 is visible again.
Returning false from HideFrame will stop this from happening.

Comment: There's no submit action on the form so I don't see how

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as there's a form. See http://jsfiddle.net/v46tF/1/ for example.

Comment: `<input type="image" ...>` operates in exactly the same way as `<input type="submit" ...>`.

Comment: @JamesWood See http://jsfiddle.net/v46tF/2/ for an updated way of toggling two images (using jQuery)